# Does an Office Open XML inspector tool exist?

Tags: ms-word, openxml

Does anyone know if a tool exists that lets you inspect Office Open XML (e.g., a Microsoft Word .docx file) in the same manner that Chrome lets you view the fully rendered web page alongside the underlying element structure and interact with it in real-time?

I am working on a project where I need to be able to do some fairly fine-tuned, programmatic manipulation of docx files.  Having such a tool would really help provide a better understanding of the Office Open XML spec and its behavior.

Kind regards.

Comment: The Open XML SDK comes with productivity tool https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/04/open-xml-sdk-tool-to-analyse-documents-and-generated-c-code/

Comment: Thanks.  I just had the Open XML SDK 2.5 installed on my work machine, but didn't see that package anywhere.  I'll have to ask my IT dept to recheck the installation.

Comment: I was able to get the productivity tool installed; however, it doesn't quite do what I had hoped.  It's good for auto generating C# code to generate a given set of XML (code reflection), but it doesn't let you view the XML side-by-side with how it would actually look in MS Word for example.

Answer (score 4):

I am a contributor on a new VS Code extension that can modify OOXML parts and get diffs of the xml when there are changes from outside e.g. Word edits a document in real time the way you describe. You can get it on the VS Code Marketplace:

[OOXML Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yuenm18.ooxml-viewer)

And review the code on GitHub:

[OOXML Viewer Repo](https://github.com/yuenm18/ooxml-viewer-vscode)

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a convenient tool like that. It should be relatively easy to make an Add-in that gets the relevant OOXML from the document selection, but I couldn't find anything on the [Office Add-ins Store](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?src=office&page=1&product=office%3Bword&category=productivity), or [Script Lab](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/) samples/snippets. (The closest I could find, might be this [Web Add-in sample app](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Load-and-write-Open-XML)).

With the [Open XML SDK Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425), you can also modify document and use the Compare Files feature to see the changes in the OOXML, and the code needed to reproduce them.
There are few more tools for Visual Studio and Chrome mentioned on [Eric White's Blog](http://ericwhite.com/blog/introduction-to-open-xml-series/):

- [Open XML Package Editor Power Tool for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bsivanov.OpenXMLPackageEditorforVisualStudio)
- [OOXML Tools Extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ooxml-tools/bjmmjfdegplhkefakjkccocjanekbapn?hl=en)